# Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token < (<!DOCTYPE html>) with php redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, syntax-error

In MS Edge I don't get the error. 
In Chrome I get: `Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token <`
In FF I get: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

In one of my WP plugins I have a redirect to a custom login page if three criteria are met: 1) user not logged in, 2) their IP isn't banned, and 3) they're not already on that page.

I keep getting this `uncaught syntax error: unexpected token <` referring to `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the first line of the page, and by process of elimination I discovered that if I disable the redirect line in the following block of code, I don't get the error:

```
public function __construct()
{
    add_action('template_redirect', array($this, 'logged_out'));    
}
public function logged_out()
{
    if(!is_user_logged_in())
    {
        if(myclass::blocked_ip()) 
        {
            die('Your IP address has been blocked.');
        }
        elseif(!is_page('login')) 
        {
            header('Location: '.myclass::$login);
            return;
        }
        else return;
    }
    return;
}
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I failed to mention that I only get this error on the login page itself, not on other pages.

**UPDATE**: Headers sent using php `get_headers('myurl');`

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Date: Mon, 28 Sep 2015 06:02:33 GMT
    [2] => Server: Apache
    [3] => X-Pingback: http://mysiter.net/xmlrpc.php
    [4] => Link: <http://mysiter.net/?p=135>; rel=shortlink
    [5] => Set-Cookie: wfvt_2830192357=5608d7fa55274; expires=Mon, 28-Sep-2015 06:32:34 GMT; path=/; httponly
    [6] => Vary: Accept-Encoding
    [7] => Connection: close
    [8] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
)
```

Comment: What is the HTML that is output? Seems like myclass::$login has a full html page. It should just be a url.

Comment: It is just a url. The class is actually called, ss_urls.

Comment: Post the rendered html that js is choking on. That's the only way to see for sure.

Comment: It's choking on <!DOCYTPE html>

Comment: Beyond that I'm not sure what you want me to post

Comment: It is rendering html and sending that to your browser. Your browser is having an issue with that html. Open your developer tools or inspector in the browser and see what php output for it.

Comment: Also, I disabled all my custom js and still got the error. It's only when the header ('Location... is in there that the error occurs.

Comment: That's not any clearer an instruction. You want me to post the entire page?

Comment: Ok. So if there is no html it is trying to do a header redirect. Can you post the headers sent as seen by the browser?

Comment: There is an entire page's worth of html. It shouldn't be doing the redirect because it's in the if (!is_page ('login'))  conditional

Comment: Just to be clear, I've had my developer tools console open for about an hour before I decided to post here. The whole page is output. The error is occurring on the very first line of the html: <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: What are the headers sent from the server?

Comment: What exactly do you want me to post, and where exactly would I find what you want me to post?

Comment: You're back end is either trying to do a redirect via JavaScript or via 302 header redirect. To know for sure where it's failing I need to see the html and the response headers sent. Both are in your developer tools. I'm guessing the header is bad at this point.

Comment: I updated the post with the results of a `get_headers()`

The header is not bad. There is no JavaScript redirect anywhere. The error occurs on the first line of the html, as I've said, but all the html is output with no problems.

Comment: Host: mysiter.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: wordfence_verifiedHuman=d55bf7a781
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0

Comment: @Thom you must be getting spaces before `Doctype` try removing spaces before doctype and remove also browser cache, its seems like you have spaces just before it.

Comment: Thanks, but there are no spaces before doctype.